# A trigonometric integral and algebraic integral limit of the same kind

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Evaluate the value of:

$$(i)\lim_{n \to ∞} n^2 \left(\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x))^{1/n} dx-\sqrt2 \right)$$
$$(ii)\lim_{n \to ∞} n^2 \left(\int_0^1 (x^n+(1-x)^n)^{1/n} dx-3/4 \right)$$

Both of these limits have a similar form and it's easy to see that it is a $0$ times $∞$ form; it is easy to evaluate both integrals by using the sandwich theorem.

In (i), for example, first I broke it into two integrals from $0$ to $\pi/4$ and $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$ and noted that $\sin(x)>\cos(x)$ in the first interval and vice versa in the second interval. Using these facts, I put a lower bound and upper bound on the integral;

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}2^{1/n} \sin x dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} 2^{1/n} \cos x dx<\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x))^{1/n} dx <\int_0^{\pi/4}2^{1/n} \cos x dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} 2^{1/n} \sin x dx $$

Upon passing the limit, the value of the integral came out to be $\sqrt2$. Similarly, for the second integral, I broke it down into an interval from $0$ to $1/2$ and $1/2$ to $1$ to obtain $3/4$. But, how do I evaluate these infinity times zero indeterminate forms using the sandwich theorem or anything?

Comment: Both integrals look like $\int_0^a (f(x)^n +f(a-x)^n)^{1/n}\,dx$ with $f(x)\in(0,1) $ for every $x\in(0,a)$ and $f(a) =1$.

Comment: And in the first case, $f(x)$ is symmetric about $x=a/2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider the case (i) - the case (ii) is similar.

$$I(n)=\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x))^{1/n} dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^3x\left(1+\tan^nx\right)^{1/n}dx$$
$$\overset{\tan x=t}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+t^n)^{1/n}}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}dt=2\int_0^1\frac{(1+t^n)^{1/n}}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}dt=2\int_0^1\frac{e^{\frac1n\ln(1+t^n)}}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}dt$$
The function $\ln(1+t^n)\leqslant\ln2$ on the given interval. Decomposing the exponent and integrating term by term
$$I(n)=2\int_0^1\left(1+\frac1n\ln(1+t^n)+\frac1{2n^2}\ln^2(1+t^n)+...\right)\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$=2\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}+\frac2n\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t^n)}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}dt+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
Making the substitution $x=t^{n}$ in the second term
$$=\sqrt2+\frac2{n^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}x\frac{x^{1/n}}{(1+x^{2/n})^{3/2}}\,dx+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
But the function $\frac{x^{1/n}}{(1+x^{2/n})^{3/2}}$ is majorized by $1$  on the interval $[0;1]$. Taking the limit $n\to\infty$ under the integral sign (DCT)
$$I(n)=\sqrt2+\frac1{\sqrt2\,n^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}xdx+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)=\sqrt2+\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt2\,n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
The limit follows.

Using the similar approach you will find that
$$(ii)\lim_{n \to ∞} n^2 \left(\int_0^1 (x^n+(1-x)^n)^{1/n} dx-3/4 \right)=\frac{\pi^2}{48}$$

Comment: How do you get a result which DEPENDS on $\color{red}{\LARGE n}$ ?.

Comment: @Felix Marin, thank you for catching this. It's a typo. Corrected.